# Cannot make request to springboot app because of CORS

Tags: java, spring-boot, cors

I try to make a POST request to my springboot app hosted on heroku,

```
const email = 'x@x.com';
const password = 'x';

const data = JSON.stringify({
    email,
    password
});

fetch(
    'https://culinareat-test.herokuapp.com/api/user/users/_login', 
    {
        method: 'POST',
        headers : {
            'Accept' : 'application/json',
            'Content-Type' : 'application/json'
        },
        body : data,
    }
).then(res => {
    console.log(res);
})
```

I got this as the response: 
[image: Response]

This is the controller on my springboot app:

```
@RestController
@AllArgsConstructor
public class UserController {

    private final UserService userService;

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST, value = "/user/users/_login")
    public LoginResponse logUserIn(@RequestBody LoginRequest loginRequest, HttpServletResponse response, HttpServletRequest request){
        return userService.logUserIn(loginRequest, response, request);
    }

    //another endpoints
}
```

I tried to do this from another articles i just read on stackoverflow:

```
@Configuration
public class AppConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {

    @Override
    public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry) {
        registry.addMapping("/**").allowedMethods("*");
    }
}
```

Still, it does nothing and i still cannot do the request.
Any recommendation what should i do? Is there anything i should add on the server-side? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You need to add annotation @CrossOrigin in your controller

```
@RestController
@CrossOrigin(origins = "*", maxAge = 3600)
@AllArgsConstructor
public class UserController {

    private final UserService userService;

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST, value = "/user/users/_login")
    public LoginResponse logUserIn(@RequestBody LoginRequest loginRequest, HttpServletResponse response, HttpServletRequest request){
        return userService.logUserIn(loginRequest, response, request);
    }

    //another endpoints
}
```

Comment: I tried this but it still receiving the same response as above

Comment: You can see this [ article ](https://bezkoder.com/spring-boot-jwt-authentication/), i think you need to implement **WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter** class

Comment: Can you be more specific for the code that i should implements? I already wrote http.cors().and().csrf().disable()

Comment: Can i see response after you add @CrossOrigin annotation

Comment: Nothing changed from the response above

Comment: I think the data in post request not match with request body in controller, data should have format 
`{"email":email, "password":password}`

Answer (score -1):

Keep in mind that cross-origin issues are raised by Browsers. By default, if you are running javascript on origin `http://localhost`, you cannot specify CORS for `localhost` on the back-end.

Browsers such as Chrome do not allow javascript running on origin `http://localhost` to share resources in a cross-origin manner. See answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/10892392/15262845.

The solution is simple. Resolve a domain, e.g., `example.com` to `127.0.0.1` in `hosts` file. Then request `example.com:8080` or `example.com` to load your front-end application and post the request from `example.com` origin.

---

Besides, you can always debug CORS by navigating to `Network` tab and copy, paste these two following headers.

```
access-control-allow-credentials: true
access-control-allow-origin: http://example.com/
```